# Using flexsearch document results in "Document only refers to a type"

Tags: angular, flexsearch

I have an Angular app that uses flexsearch@0.7.31

I import the Document object, but when I try to call the constructor I get "Document only refers to a type".

The index.d.ts file indeed defines Document as an interface, with the Document object in src/document.js not exposed as a type.

I'm not sure how to get this to work.

```
import { Document } from "flexsearch";
...
const researchplanIndex = new Document({
      language: lang,
      document: {
        id: 'id',
        index: [
          'objective',
          'items[]:title',
          'items[]:note',
          'items[]:repository',
        ],
      },
    });
```

The error occurs at new Document

Answer (score 1):

You should use external typings, not included to the main package flexsearch which is wrong.
Use @types/flexsearch instead.

npm install --save-dev @types/flexsearch

To point out to use @types/flexsearch modify your tsconfig.json

```
"paths": {
  "flexsearch": ["node_modules/@types/flexsearch"]
}
```

This problem occurred with any usage of flexsearch types, for example:

> error TS2693: 'Index' only refers to a type, but is being used as a
> value here.
>
> const index = new Index();

Answer (score 1):

For those who face the same issue. Found this way to make it works for ESM:

```
import Document from "flexsearch/dist/module/document";
```

following this thread:
https://github.com/nextapps-de/flexsearch/issues/341#issuecomment-1640961525